# Finding which array contributes the maximum value for classification

Tags: python, numpy

Given 2 2x2 Numpy arrays, each element having a value between 0 and 1, I would like to find the one array of the 2 that has the maximum value, and do that comparison element-wise. For example, given:

`A = [[.6 .2] [.3 .4]]` and `B = [[.4 .5] [.7 .1]]`, I would like something like: `[[A B] [A B]]` back. Ideally, the output will be some number, `[[1 2] [1 2]]`, where 1 represents A, and 2 represents B. That way, if I compare, say, 10 arrays, the output will have an integer between 1 and 10 as each element, which can easily be plotted in a pcolor plot.

If I simply combine those arrays into one 2x2x2 and do np.amax(combined_array, axis=0), I get the maximum value, but don't know which array it comes from.

The purpose of all this is that each array represents a category and contains probabilities of that category occurring. I would like to know for each element position [0][0], [0][1], [1][0], and [1][1], which category is the most probable one occurring at that position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a combined array of 10 of your 2x2 matrices like the one randomly generated by

```
a = numpy.random.randn(10, 2, 2)
```

you can get the desired indices by

```
a.argmax(axis=0)
```